# django-filtered-fields ManyToManyByLetter with a field from foreign key

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-filtered-fields and would like to choose UserProfiles (a foreign key in my model) in my form with ManyToManyByLetter, but I would like them to be listed alphabetically by user's username. The code below doesn't work. It gives an error 'Cannot resolve keyword 'user.username''.

```
ManyToManyByLetter(UserProfile, field_name="user.username")
```

I hope there is some solution to this, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: try: ManyToManyByLetter(UserProfile, field_name="user__username") but the code (https://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-filtered-fields/source/browse/ajax_filtered_fields/forms/fields.py#150) suggest that solution